# How to change class of button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the icon of a button when clicked.

With the following code I have managed to change the icon when first clicked, but it doesn't change back when clicked again.

**HTML**

```
<button class="toggle-button custom-navbar-toggle">
    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('.custom-navbar-toggle').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('not-clicked')){
        $this.html('<i class="material-icons clicked">menu</i>'); 

    } else {
        $this.html('<i class="material-icons not-clicked">check</i>'); 

    }
});
```

How can I get the button to change back once clicked again?

Comment: `$this.hasClass` checks to see if the `<button>` has a specific class. You're applying a class to the `<i>` element. Look into `$this.addClass` and `$this.removeClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A better approach is `addClass()` and `removeClass()` like below:-***

```
$('.custom-navbar-toggle').click(function(){
    if($(this).children('i').hasClass('not-clicked')){
        $(this).children('i').removeClass('not-clicked').addClass('clicked').html('menu'); 
    } else {
        $(this).children('i').removeClass('clicked').addClass('not-clicked').html('check'); 
    }
});
```

Example:-

```js
$('.custom-navbar-toggle').click(function(){
  if($(this).children('i').hasClass('not-clicked')){
      $(this).children('i').removeClass('not-clicked').addClass('clicked').html('menu'); 
  } else {
      $(this).children('i').removeClass('clicked').addClass('not-clicked').html('check'); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggle-button custom-navbar-toggle">
  <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</button>
```

***Note:- your initial code is adding class to children `<i>`, so you have to check class also on children itself, not on button.***

So you have to do it like below:-

```
$('.custom-navbar-toggle').click(function(){
    if($(this).children('i').hasClass('not-clicked')){
        $(this).html('<i class="material-icons clicked">menu</i>'); 
    } else {
        $(this).html('<i class="material-icons not-clicked">check</i>'); 
    }
});
```

EXAMPLE:-

```js
$('.custom-navbar-toggle').click(function(){
  if($(this).children('i').hasClass('not-clicked')){
      $(this).html('<i class="material-icons clicked">menu</i>'); 
  } else {
      $(this).html('<i class="material-icons not-clicked">check</i>'); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle-button custom-navbar-toggle">
  <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</button>
```

Comment: @andrew_  i have added a better approach too. Please check and don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Give "not-clicked" class by default.

```
<button class="toggle-button custom-navbar-toggle">
    <i class="material-icons not-clicked">menu</i>
</button>
```

Then using toggerClass function you can add remove class names to i tag

```
$('.custom-navbar-toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("not-clicked").toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$this` only target `$('.custom-navbar-toggle')` which is the parent of the `i`, you need go down to the child to call `.hasClass`

use `find('i')` or children()

```js
$('.custom-navbar-toggle').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.find('i').hasClass('not-clicked')) {
    $this.html('<i class="material-icons clicked">menu</i>');
  } else {
    $this.html('<i class="material-icons not-clicked">check</i>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggle-button custom-navbar-toggle">
    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
</button>
```